# YouTube Data API V3 quota limited to 0

Tags: youtube-data-api

Google Cloud support has suggested this is the forum for my question, rather than them, so here goes...

Existing project is working with Maps Platform (and in production for a few years).  Trying to add YouTube Data API V3.

I have enabled the API on the project and created an API Key, but the Queries per Day quota is set to 0 and not editable. It did not default to the 10,000 per day as specified in the documentation. The "Queries per minute per user" and "Queries per minute" did default to     180,000 and         1,800,000 respectively, but the "Queries per day" of 0 is blocking access to API completely with the message:

"The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota."

The edit quota icon is greyed out and displays "This limit may not be edited"

How do I enable access to the API so I can start developing a solution with my existing project?

Comment: "Google Cloud support has suggested this is the forum for my question, rather than them" - I think they are wrong...

Comment: I fully agree - but after more than 2 hours of being given the round around and transferred from department to department they gave up and sent me 2 links for documentation and support for Youtube Data V3 API and then quoted those documents telling me to go here. 8(